# MediaPlayer to play sound effects

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that uses the Android MediaPlayer function to play sound effects on the click of an ImageButton like so:

```
final MediaPlayer LowTomPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(HomeScreen.this, R.raw.low_tom);
ImageButton btn_low_tom = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.low_tom);

btn_low_tom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(LowTomPlayer.isPlaying())
        {  
            LowTomPlayer.pause();
            LowTomPlayer.start();
        }
        else
            LowTomPlayer.start();



    }

});
```

Only problem is, that since I am telling it to pause when the effect is playing, then start again, It doesn't change anything.

The Sound Effect in question is about a second long, so if the user hammers on the button to play the sound again within that time, it won't. I want it to have the capability to stop the effect if it is playing, then restart it from the beginning when the user clicks the button again.

What I've figured out is that there is no capability to stop the media player without clearing it back to being uninitialized. What I am asking is if anyone can figure out a syntax that will have that same effect without creating a ton of different media players.

If anything isn't clear, just ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
final MediaPlayer LowTomPlayer = MediaPlayer
        .create(this, R.raw.low_tom);
try {
    LowTomPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

ImageButton btn_low_tom = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.low_tom);

btn_low_tom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (LowTomPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            LowTomPlayer.pause();
        } else
            LowTomPlayer.start();

    }

});
```

try this code.

Comment: Actually, Scratch that, It

Comment: is only pausing it when you hit the button again, and then finishing the rest of the audio clip. I need it to start from the beginning every time you hit the button. An ideas?

Comment: did you try puting LowTomPlayer.stop(); instead of LowTomPlayer.pause();